# Gutenberg block have to be resolved to display the right editing view

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, jsx, wordpress-gutenberg

I need a little help with Wordpress Gutenberg Block Editor since i made a block that was working pretty well.

One thing was missing, I decided to add an anchor tag  '' between one of my props variables in the save function.

What I did first was to add a new input tag in edit function to update the href attribute of my anchor.

Everything works fine on the front. The only problem I have is in the backoffice Gutenberg article editor, my bloc returns the HTML of the save function instead of the one of the edit function.

So Wordpress give me an error and i always need to press the button resolve to see the html of the save function.

I give you my code, I want to know if you see something strange, or if you maybe know the issue :

```
const {registerBlockType} = wp.blocks
const {InspectorControls, MediaUpload} = wp.editor

registerBlockType('astra/ingreds', {
    title: 'Ligne d\'Ingrédient',
    category: 'widgets',
    icon: 'smiley',
    attributes: {
        ingName: {type: "string"},
        ingQtt: {type: "string"},
        mediaID: {type: "string"},
        mediaURL: {type: "string"},
        bgurl: {type: "string"},
        ingLink: {type: "string"}
    },
    edit: function(props) {
        function updateIngName(e){
            props.setAttributes({ingName : e.target.value})
        }
        function updateIngQtt(e){
            props.setAttributes({ingQtt : e.target.value})
        }
        function updateLink(e){
            props.setAttributes({ingLink : e.target.value})
        }
    return (
            <div className="anton-cont-recette" id="container-recipe">
                <div className="ing-row">
                    <input className="ing-link" type="text" placeholder="Lien du produit" onChange={updateLink} value={props.attributes.ingLink}/>
                    <div className="ing-picto" style={{backgroundImage: props.attributes.bgurl}}></div>
                    <input className="ing-name" type="text" placeholder="Ingrédient" onChange={updateIngName} value={props.attributes.ingName}/>
                    <input className="ing-qtt"  type="text" placeholder="Quantité" onChange={updateIngQtt} value={props.attributes.ingQtt}/>
                </div>
                <InspectorControls>
                    <h2>Sélectionnez une image pour l'ingrédient {props.attributes.ingName}</h2>
                    <MediaUpload
                     type="image"
                     onSelect={image => props.setAttributes({mediaID: image.id, mediaURL: image.sizes.full.url, bgurl: "url('"+image.sizes.full.url+"')"})}
                     value={ props.attributes.mediaID }
                     render={
                        ({open}) =>(
                            <button onClick={open}>Choisir une image</button>
                            )
                     }
                    />          
                </InspectorControls>
            </div>
        )
    },
    save: function (props) {
        const backgroundImg = 'background-image: url('+props.attributes.mediaURL+')'; 
        return (
                 <div className="row ing-line">
                     <div className="ing-picto" style={backgroundImg}></div>
                     <div className="ing-holder">
                         <span className="ingName"><a href={props.attributes.ingLink} target="_blank">{props.attributes.ingName}</a></span>
                         <span className="ingQtt">{props.attributes.ingQtt}</span>
                     </div>
                 </div>)
    }
})
```

Comment: If you open the console in the editor when you first load the post, it will show you what is different between what HTML is saved in the database and what Gutenberg tried to render from the `save` function. That will help you start to track down where the issue is.

Comment: You are right thank you for the clue ;)

Answer (score 0):

After Phil recommandations i saw in the console those lines of errors:

```
blocks.min.js?ver=e2b6602c7ebbe8ce93832ce35d81be1c:2 Block validation: Block validation failed for `astra/ingreds` ({name: 'astra/ingreds', icon: {…}, keywords: Array(0), attributes: {…}, providesContext: {…}, …}).

Content generated by `save` function:

<div class="wp-block-astra-ingreds row ing-line"><div class="ing-picto" style="background-image: url(undefined)"></div><div class="ing-holder"><span class="ingName"><a target="_blank"></a></span><span class="ingQtt"></span></div></div>

Content retrieved from post body:

<div class="wp-block-astra-ingreds row ing-line"><div class="ing-picto" style="background-image: url(undefined)"></div><div class="ing-holder"><span class="ingName"><a target="_blank" rel="noopener"></a></span><span class="ingQtt"></span></div></div>
```

The only thing that was different between these two was the attribute rel from the anchor tag, that i didn't declared and/so that was created by default by post body.

so i just written in my save function "rel = noopener" and you know what? It worked !

Thank you to Phil and his knowledge of how to debug gutenberg blocks!

Have a nice day !